# Increase space on part/lvm or mount

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, aws, plesk

So, long story short, got a server(EC2) with 2 EBS pointed to it. (100G & 200G).
Upon investigation, I come across that the /var/www mount has only 50GB assigned.
My requirement is to increase this 50GB's to 100GB if possible.

The structure of the disk is as the below image.[image]

Above is the output I get when I run the `lsblk` command.

Below is what it seems to be running on.
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
17.8.11 cos6.build1708180301.19

This also has Plesk installed. I am open to installing a plugin.

-----PVS,VGS,LVS

PVS Output

```
PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
/dev/xvdj1 data lvm2 a--u 50.00g    0
```

VGS Output

```
VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
data   1   1   0 wz--n- 50.00g    0
```

LVS Output

```
LV   VG   Attr      LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
www  data -wi-ao---- 50.00g
```

Comment: Please add the output of `pvs` and `vgs` and `lvs` to your question.  This may impact the answer.   Also, please don't post screenshots, but cut'n'paste the text.

Comment: Please avoid using images when text will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to make sure the PV (Physical Volume) on `/dev/xvdj1` takes the whole partition. You can do that by running

```
pvresize /dev/xvdj1
```

This will resize the PV to take all available space. See `man pvresize` for more options.

After that, you can resize the LV (Logical Volume); for example:

```
lvresize --resizefs --size 88G /dev/data/www
```

to resize the device to 88GB. Use

```
lvresize --resizefs -l 100%FREE /dev/data/www
```

to allocate all free space in the VG to the `data/www` LV. See `man lvresize` for more options.

For more information on LVM, see [An Introduction to LVM Concepts, Terminology, and Operations](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-lvm-concepts-terminology-and-operations%20%22%22)

Comment: You sir, are a legend. Worked like a charm. Thank you so much